# Issues with coordinates in Solr during updating of fields

Tags: solr

I have an implementation of storing the coordinates in `Solr` during indexing. 
During indexing, I will only store the value in the field `name ="gps"`. For the field `name = "gps_0_coordinate"` and `"gps_1_coordinate"`, the value will be auto filled and indexed from the `"gps"` field.

```
<field name="gps" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
<field name="gps_0_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
<field name="gps_1_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
```

But when I tried to do an update on any other fields in the index, Solr will try to add another value in the `"gps_0_coordinate"` and `"gps_1_coordinate"`. However, as these 2 fields are not multi-Valued, it will lead to an error:
multiple values encountered for non multiValued field

```
gps_0_coordinate: [1.0,1.0]
```

Does anyone knows how we can solve this issue?

I am using `Solr 5.4.0`

Comment: You shouldn't have to create the `gps_0_coordinate` fields yourself any longer - as far as I remember the spatial fields handle all that logic internally (using "shadow"-fields with names like that)

Comment: I have tried to leave out the `gps_0_coordinate` field, and I get the following error.     
  
    `ERROR: [doc=id1] unknown field 'gps_0_coordinate'`

Comment: Yes - seems like the LatLonType still require those manually added. You could try using a different type - see the spatial documentation in the manual for the more recent fieldtypes to deal with spatial data. If you can replicate it as a small example on 6.0, I'd suggest creating a bug ticket at the Apache JIRA.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried it in Solr 6.0, and the same problem exists.